# the difference of always and initial

Tags: verilog

I have this test to count 1's in a byte. If the always block to count number of 1's is in tb, it won't work, but it is working when it is moved to a module.

```
module for_zero_count_tb;

   reg [7:0] data;
   
   wire [7:0] sum;
    reg [7:0] sum1;
   
   integer    i;
   
   initial begin
     data = 16'he;
     sum1 = 0;
    end
   
    always @(*) begin
    for(i = 0; i<=7 ;i = i+ 1)
      begin
     if (data[i] == 1'b1)
         sum1 = sum1 + 1;
        end
    end
   
initial begin
   $monitor($realtime, "ns  data = %b, sum = %d sum1 = %d", data, sum, sum1);   
 end
   for_zero_count uut(data, sum);
   

endmodule
```

the output sum is 3, and sum1 is 0. I thought sum1 should also be 3.

What's the issue here?

thanks

Comment: what does it mean: *always block is in tb* ? how *doesn't* it work? yours looks like a correct code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition between your `initial` and `always` block. Both of them start at time 0, but simulation will choose one or the other to go first. If the `initial` block goes first, `data` changes first before the `always @*` executes and blocks waiting for the next change. A tool that chooses the `always @*` first gives you the results you are expecting.

To guarantee that any Verilog simulator gives you the results you are expect, you need add a delay to the first change to `data`. SystemVerilog addresses this time 0 race with the `always_comb` construct. If executes the procedural code inside the construct at least once at time 0.

Once other problem with your code is that you need to set `sum1=0` at the beginning of the `always` so that it does not accumulate the count of ones for different values of data.

Comment: but how come moving the always to a module will get a different (correct) result? Do they suffer same race condition?

Comment: Same race condition. Signals going through ports may have have an impact on ordering.